# Calling custom method with &: syntax om Ruby

Tags: ruby

So basically I was looking at this simple example:

```
%w[A B C].map(&:downcase)
```

And got interested in the `&:` syntax. After reading some articles I think I got the point (or at least I think so) so I've decided to implement something similar for `Integer` like this:

```
class Integer
  def my_multiplier
    puts "66"
  end
end
```

And here I can get advantage of the `&:` syntax cause I am allowed to do so:

`3.times(&:my_multiplier)`

But of course the result is three times the number `66`.

My questions is how to refactor my method so I can actually use the values from `3.times..`?

Comment: Try using `return` instead of `puts`.

Comment: Changing the behavior is not called refactoring. Particularly, if your code does not work, and you want it to be changed to work, then that is called debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the syntax is `&object`, not `&:`. `&object` calls `.to_proc` on the object.

Now, assuming you'd like your multiplier to simply puts your integer multiplied by 66, you'd write it as:

```
class Integer
  def my_multiplier
    puts 66 * self
  end
end
```

Which will result in

```
2.5.1 :006 > 3.times(&:my_multiplier)
0
66
132
```

This is the equivalent of calling

```
3.times { |i| i.my_multiplier }
```

You can also define your `my_multiplier` as a proc or a lambda,

```
2.5.1 :001 > p = ->(i) { puts i * 66 }
 => #<Proc:0x00005582b3ae5638@(irb):1 (lambda)> 
2.5.1 :002 > 3.times(&p)
0
66
132
```

Comment: " the syntax is &object, not &:" - yes. of course, but that idea is _really_ hard to shake off. I _still_ think of that as "&: notation". I don't know why.

Comment: I understand, but it's still important to mention in my opinion, especially if you're trying to understand what's going on beneath.

Comment: I am confused - `:` indicates symbol and `&` indicates passing block as parameter. If that is generally correct how comes that `(&:my_multiplier)`  is actually .. Hmm, I was about to say `&Integer.to_proc` but obv. Integer is the class here not the object. I am confused. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, `&:my_multiplier` calls `to_proc` on `:my_multiplier`. `to_proc` is defined on symbols to simply call the method with the same name as the symbol. Calling `3.times(&:my_multiplier)` is the equivalent of calling `3.times { |i| i.my_multiplier}`. I've added an example where `my_multiplier` is defined as a proc.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you were shooting for with that method, but current integer will be available as `self`. So you can do something like this:

```
class Integer
  def double 
    self * 2
  end 

end

3.times.map(&:double) # => [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: You got it right. The part that I was wondering was `self * 2`. However I got more confused by your comment on the other answer - why the syntax is not `&:`

Comment: @Leron: looks like Marcin nailed the explanation there.